# Windows 7 tablet development help and guidance

Tags: c#, .net, intel, tablet, intel-atom

I am facing a tiny development project for an Intel Atom based Windows 7 tablet `Motion LE1600` or a `Fujitsu 5112`.

I have never done Windows tablet development. My main concern is what are my options here? I am looking towards a pure managed solution using NET 4 and WPF. Is that possible?

Does Windows 7 tablet fall into a category of mobile development?

Any help is appreciated. I could not find many online resources describing these topics.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://windows7multitouch.codeplex.com) in this portal you will find some example with WPF and tablets and [here](http://www.windowstecnico.com/archive/tags/Tablet/default.aspx) with more explanation.